# iptables redirect dns to proxy

Tags: iptables, dns, squid

Can we redirect DNS (tcp/udp) requests to Squid proxy in non-transparent mode (3128) using iptables? (Would the squid proxy understand this and process it?)

example rule to redirect tcp 53 (It could be another similar):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128
```

example rule to redirect udp 53 (It could be another similar):

Note: Squid "listen" high udp port. example: 36352, Command: netstat -tlunp | grep squid

reference: http://linuxplayer.org/2012/02/why-squid-listen-on-high-udp-port-number

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -i eth1 -p udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-port 36352
```

PD: These are just examples of squid directives related to DNS. I am not claiming that they serve my purposes:

```
positive_dns_ttl 
negative_dns_ttl 
dns_nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
udp_incoming_address
```

If this can not be done, I accept alternatives

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Squid is not a DNS proxy and does not accept DNS requests.

Looking at the documentation for the directives you highlight it's quite clear these are for internal settings and have nothing to do with external client access:

- [`positive_dns_ttl`](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/positive_dns_ttl/)
- [`negative_dns_ttl`](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/negative_dns_ttl/)
- [`dns_nameservers`](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/dns_nameservers/)
- [`udp_incoming_address`](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/udp_incoming_address/)

In explicit response to your last sentence/question, there are no alternative ways to direct DNS traffic to a Squid proxy, because Squid does not proxy DNS traffic.

Further reading

- [Can squid forward DNS queries to a DNS server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2617273/2344631)
- [Setting up Explicit Squid Proxy - DNS Configuration](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Setting_up_Explicit_Squid_Proxy#DNS_configuration)
- [Squid Proxy: DNS Requests](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/squid-proxy-dns-requests-738896/)

---

I've been thinking some more about this, and trying to second-guess the problem you actually want to solve. You do realise that although Squid doesn't proxy DNS requests, all standard DNS servers do this? Examples I can cite include Dnsmasq and Bind.

Comment: in this site, say the opposite http://linuxplayer.org/2012/02/why-squid-listen-on-high-udp-port-number

Comment: @ajcg no it doesn't. That [article](http://linuxplayer.org/2012/02/why-squid-listen-on-high-udp-port-number) says the same as I do: that the DNS service is to manage Squid's internal queries.

Comment: Could you add to your answer the redirect alternative using as a dnsmasq gateway? (to select it as correct). Thanks

Comment: There are already plenty of questions and answers relating to dnsmasq. I've answered your question here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually the problem I have is that I can not redirect to the proxy the android (because they do not support automatic proxy) and so I tried to redirect their requests dns to the proxy. I thank you for giving me a link where I can check the solution (I have searched and I have not found it). Thanks in advance

Comment: Set up a DNS server and use `iptables` to redirect all DNS requests (UDP _and_ TCP) to the server. Better still, provide the correct information as part of the DHCP response to your phone devices.

Comment: android is not compatible with dhcp 252 or wpad (pac files)

Comment: DHCP option 252 is WPAD, and has nothing to do with DNS.

Comment: so I do not understand. What do you mean by "Better still, provide the correct information as part of the DHCP response to your phone devices"